# accessing datagrid selected row values in jquery

Tags: jquery, gridview, click, row

I am trying to get the entire datagrid row on checkbox selection .
but I can get only the value of id which is bound to checkbox but not others. My code is below:

```
function btnClick() {
    var mytext
    var gridView1Control = document.getElementById('<%= indivPrincipalGrid.ClientID %>');

    $('#<%= btnGetData.ClientID %>').click(function(e) {
       $('input:checkbox[id$=CheckSelect]:checked', gridView1Control).each(function(item, index) {

            var id = $(this).next('input:hidden[id$=hdID]').val();
            var nm = $(this).find('input:hidden[id$=hdID1]').val();
            alert(id);
            alert(nm);
        });
        return false;

    });
```

my grid is as follows :

```
<div>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="test"Font-Bold = "true"></asp:Label>
    <asp:GridView ID="indivPrincipalGrid" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
   <asp:BoundField  DataField = "Name"/>
   <asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckSelect" runat="server" /> 
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ID")%>'/> 
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdID1" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Name")%>'/>        

    </ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField></Columns></asp:GridView>

    <asp:Button ID="btnGetData" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick = "btnClick()" />

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK..
I found that the function supposed to populate the hidden cntrl wasn't working ok and hence i was getting undefined in client script. Fixing it resolved the issue. Thanks all for help.

Answer (score 0):

See the commented line, where first i find the parent then i find the controls. Hopefully this will work perfectly

function btnClick() {
    var mytext
    var gridView1Control = document.getElementById('<%= indivPrincipalGrid.ClientID %>');

```
$('#<%= btnGetData.ClientID %>').click(function(e) {
   $('input:checkbox[id$=CheckSelect]:checked', gridView1Control).each(function(item, index) {


        var id = $(this).next('input:hidden[id$=hdID]').val();
        //find the row which is tr in this case. and then find the hidden control
        var parent=$(this).parent('tr');
        var nm = parent.find('input:hidden[id$=hdID1]').val();
        alert(id);
        alert(nm);
    });
    return false;

});
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply but i still get undefined in alert for name